# Tense with an improbable condition

Tags: sentence-meaning, tense

What is the difference between these two sentences?

1. *If he **asked** me, I **would/'d** stay.*
2. *If he **had/'d** asked me, I **would/'d have** stayed.*

I think they both are conveying the same meaning, That is a counterfactual condition in the past.

Source: Textbook (Commom mistakes in English, Longman)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They do not convey the same meaning.

1. He hasn't asked me yet, but he may do so.
2. He might have asked me (on an earlier occasion), but he didn't.

Comment: "If he asks me, I will/'ll stay" also conveys he hasn't asked me yet, but he may do so. Then what is the difference between this one and 1st one (If he asked me, I would/'d stay)?

Comment: 'If he asks me' - (it's quite likely that he will). 'If he asked me' has the same sense as 'If he were to ask me' - it makes his asking you a bit more hypothetical (you are not at all sure that he will).

Comment: I just can't digest the fact that "_if he asked me_" points at some future possibility. i.e. if this happen, then [that will happen] and the outcome is in past

Comment: Okay, just one more example, I believe it'll make me all clear:- 1. If I study, I'll pass the exam -- conveys that exam hasn't happened yet, will happen in future for sure and If I prepare for that exam, I'll pass. 2. If I had studied, I would have passed the exam -- conveys that exam has happened and I failed in that exam. 3. If I studied, I would pass the exam -- ?? What does this convey? I'm only confused about this last sentence.

Comment: "If I study, I will pass the exam" - the speaker intends to study hard. "If I studied, I would pass the exam" could be followed by "...but I'm not going to bother, because passing that exam wouldn't really help me in my career."

Comment: I got your point. But I still don't understand that in this example ( *If I studied, I would/'d pass the exam*) When speaker gave this statement, **has the exam happened or not?**

Comment: No - if it had, it would be  _I would have passed_.

Answer (score 0):

*Subjunctive mood* is the issue involved. **Both** of those sentences could have been written in the subjunctive mood as such:
**If he were to have asked me, then I would have stayed.**

However, for at least 20 years, I've noticed that native English speakers sometimes do not use the subjunctive mood in both informal, and formal, speech. So, it is fair to say that not using subjunctive mood is not incorrect. Rather, the subjunctive mood is exiting the language.

Myself, a native speaker who chooses to use subjunctive mood, I sort of "auto-correct" both these sentences into the same subjunctive mood sentence that I wrote above. Thus they mean the same thing to me:
*If he asked me, I would/'d stay.*
*If he had/'d asked me, I would/'d have stayed.*